# Java3d resetting to a new scene

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm working on a game in Java3D. I read all my level info from a file and it works fine. But now I want to re-initialize the scene from reading data from a different file.

How do I reset the scene?

Should I just destroy the whole canvas3D and universe objects?

Comment: can't you detach and attach scene graphs? destroying the whole canvas sounds extreme. but im not sure so I am hesitant to claim its an answer

Comment: I can I think but I'm not sure of the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mikeb, you put me on the right track.

I figured it out. You need to detach the branchgroup.

Like this:

```
if (sceneBG != null) {
   sceneBG.detach();
}
sceneBG = new BranchGroup();
sceneBG.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
```